# Set header in CUPS response

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, ubuntu-14.04, cups

I am trying to communicate with a cups server from javascript in the browser but I am running into cross origin policy.

Anyone have any wisdom for setting headers in the cups response?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.  From the cups config file and the logging output, it looks like cups makes use of apache.  But `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` doesn't work.  I just get lots of `Unknown Location directive Header on line` error output in `/var/log/cups/error_log`